# unable to access tableviewcell's property in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

In my swift app, I am using table view. While selecting, I can able to change cell's background color only. But, Inside the cell, I am having label. Unable to change color of the label when cell got selected. If I create instance for UITableViewCell, "Fatal Error Receiving"

My Coding is Below. Kindly guide me. how to access that label?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    var cell_prop = list_dip_tableView() //Creating instance
    cell_prop.list_label.text.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
//ERROR: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
}
```

Comment: You should post the implementation of list_dip_tableView and the callstack of the error. Otherwise it is hard for us to help with debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` has selected property. So you can override that property in your subclass.

```
override var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if selected { 
            label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        } else {
            label.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to call. Can u explain via coding? how to call from tableview while selecting?

Comment: You don't call this code. System does. You are using custom tableviewcell right?

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, will give anything??? Its very new to me. Can u explain through coding?

Comment: Hi..!! I found out, where to place this code. It s working. But I couldn't change label's text colour. how to change??

Comment: Hi..!! another doubt..!! False condition alone working. True condition is not working?

Comment: Then in tableVievDidSelectRow methot call cell.selected= true

Comment: Atlast I found out. Thanks @ mustafa

Comment: Intially, the seperator line having some gap. how to fill separator from first?? @mustafa